# Dashboard lights are dim?

Tags: battery, lights

We own a 2011 Mitsubishi Montero Sport GTV.

We noticed that the dashboard lights were dimmer than normal. What could possibly cause this? Would replacing the battery fix this?

Comment: Probably too obvious, but is the dashboard light intensity adjustable? Some cars have a tiny knob on the dash for this adjustment.

Comment: Similar to what jensgram said... My wife's Civic was the same way after replacing the battery. Instead of the knob or dial I was used to, you had to press the +/- buttons on the dash. Check your owner's manual to see if yours is adjustable like that.

Comment: Hi @jensgram, I checked the Montero and it did not have a knob or dial to adjust the lights. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out it was just the battery. Had it replaced today and dashboard lights were back to normal. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Surprising that the battery was strong enough to start the car (at least you did not mention that as another issue) but not enough to light up the dash lights fully!